# Runing a "child" python file as regular user when main python file needs to be run as root

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm doing a python program (and using PyQt5 for GUI) that needs to be run as root (because I'm programming sockets on it). It has a button,when I click on it, it opens another python file (the "child" file: `chrometest.py`, it's based on this library, eel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kbeBzEQfXE, it lets me open a js file). The problem is that eel won't work when it's run as root, so I don't know how I could switch users to run only this function as regular user.

**Main python program (sample, the one runing as root)**

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.img = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.open_js= QtWidgets.QPushButton('Load')
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 150        
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.img.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("someimage.png"))
        self.open_js.clicked.connect(self.openjs)
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        h_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        h_layout.addWidget(self.img)
        h_layout.addWidget(self.open_js)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setGeometry(600,150,self.width,self.height)

    def openjs(self):
        #here is where I think I need to switch to regular user
        exec(open("chrometest.py").read())

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**chrometest.py (program that needs to be run as regular user)**

```
import eel
eel.init('webfiles')
eel.start('index.html')
```

I tried to use this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chown.htm in the line commented but it didn't work

Comment: It may be that your project uses PyQt to create the GUI but your current problem does not depend on the GUI or PyQt.

Answer (score 1):

It is common in Unix-like systems to have a process that needs to be root at a time, for example to listen on ports below 1024, but then executes  as a regular non priviledges user for security reasons. Whatever the language the design is as follow:

- priviledged part (extensively tested for security flaws) executes only code requiring root privileges
- as soon as code that does not require root has to be executed it forks and

  - parent remains priviledged and continue to run priviledged code
  - child switch to a regular user (allowed because it is still at priviledged-root level) and executes normal code

That is what you should do here:

```
def openjs(self):
    pid = os.fork()
    if 0 == pid:
        os.setuid(uid_of_non_priviledged_user)
        # you can now safely execute code from chrometest.
    else:
        # optionaly wait for child:
        os.waitpid(pid, os.WEXITED)
```

Answer (score 0):

oh yes!!.. you can able to run a child python file as a regular python file.but u need to add this line in your parent python file.

```
import os
os.system("python  chrometest.py")
```

by this line your parent python file can run your child python file.

Comment: I got this error: `os.system("python  chrometest.py") TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`. Should I install another program to run it?

Comment: @lissethamc: this error only means that you have mixed tabs and spaces in your source which you should never do.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mani Kandan said, you can run process by `os.system`, but if you already working under root, it will be executed with same privileges.

You can run program under specified user using `sudo -u` or `sudo --user` argument like

`sudo -u regular_user "python3 chrometest.py"`

So, in Python it will look like:

```
import os
os.system('sudo -u regular_user python3 chrometest.py')
```

and about your `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` error: change all tabs in your script to spaces or vice versa.